Why do I get Property 'x' does not exist on type '{ error: string; }'.ts(2339) when I'm trying to prefill from database?
What I did is I fetch a single data from database and created a component wherein I can edit the user's input, but I've got a warning from typescript wherein I get this.

Property 'title' does not exist on type '{ error: string; }'.ts(2339)

This is my zod schema.
const formSchemaData = z.object({
    title: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "title must be at least 2 characters.",
    }),
    email: z.string().min(2, {
      message: "email must be at least 2 characters.",
    }).email(),

    //other code   
  })

export type Events = z.infer<typeof formSchemaData>

 const { data, error, isFetching } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["eventId", eventId],
    queryFn: async () => await getDataById(eventId),
  });

  const form = useForm<Events>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchemaData),    
  });

return (
<Form {...form}>
        <form>
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="title"
          defaultValue={data ? data.title : ''} 
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <Input 
                  placeholder="title"
                  {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormDescription>
                This is your public display name.
              </FormDescription>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
)


This is how I fetch my data from database
export async function getDataById(id: any){
  try {
    const data = await db.appoinmentSchedule.findUnique({
      where: {
        id:id
      }
    })

    return data
  } catch (error) {
    return {error: "Something went wrong"}
  }
}

This is the types
Sorry I can't post the code, stack overflow is giving me a warning

Can you show getDataById and its types?

In the case where you return { error: "something went wrong" }, typescript is pointing out that defaultValue={data ? data.title : ''} doesn't make sense, since it won't have a .title property. What do you want to do in that case? Did you mean to throw that instead or returning it?

Building up on Nicholas Tower's comment, the reason for this warning becomes clearer when you manually specify the return type of getDataById:
export async function getDataById(id: any): Promise<
  | { title: any; email: string }
  | { error: string }
> {
  // ...
}

Since the return type can be both { title: any; email: string } and { error: string }, the compiler can't guarantee that your result will have the title field when setting defaultValue:
defaultValue={data ? data.title : ''}

The way to solve this is to handle the case when the error happens:
const { data, error, isFetching } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["eventId", eventId],
  queryFn: async () => await getDataById(eventId),
});

const form = useForm<Events>({
  resolver: zodResolver(formSchemaData),    
});

if ("error" in data) {
  // just an example, you should display an appropriate UI to the user
  return <>{data.error}</>;
}

// if `"error" in data` evaluates to false, then data
// must have the type of `{ title: any; email: string }`

return (
  <Form {...form}>
    <form>
      <FormField
        control={form.control}
        name="title"
        defaultValue={data ? data.title : ''} // no more warning, data.title is now surely defined
        {/* ... */}
      />
    </form>
  </Form>
)


Thanks for explaining, I'm having a hard time figuring out typescript warning haha

No problem, feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" so that others who stumble upon your question know that this answer helped you.
